# How to combine the columns of two data.tables?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two tables of the type data.table. I want to combine the tables into one table. They look like:

DT1:

```
1  A  B  C
2  A  B  C  
3  A  B  C
```

DT2:

```
D  E  F
D  E  F
D  E  F
```

I want to combine them like:

```
1  A  B  C  D  E  F
2  A  B  C  D  E  F
3  A  B  C  D  E  F
```

I don't know how I can do this by merging, because the data tables don't have common column names.

I know this is possible with cbind, but I'm working with a lot of rows, so I prefer a function which is built to work with big data tables.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Did you try `cbind(DT1, DT2)` ? Was it too slow ?

Comment: Try the data.table package.

Comment: @RonakShah I'm working with a lot of rows, and cbind is not built for that. Then R may crash. So I hope there is a better option

Comment: @jordinec `cbind` needs less resources than a join/merge.

Comment: Try `library(data.table)` and then `cbind.data.table(DT1,DT2)`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried something with some slighter bigger table (using the code provided by Hart Radev) and I've `microbenchmark`ed them, maybe it could be helpful:

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

DT1 = data.frame(A = rep('A', 300000), B = rep('B', 300000))
DT2 = data.frame(C = rep('C', 300000), D = rep('D', 300000))

microbenchmark(
bind_cols = {bind_cols(DT1, DT2)},
cbind = {cbind(DT1,DT2)},
# Hart solution
merge = { DT1$rowname = rownames(DT1) 
          DT2$rowname = rownames(DT2)
          DT3 = merge(DT1, DT2, by = 'rowname')}
)

Unit: microseconds
           expr         min           lq         mean       median           uq         max neval
      bind_cols      72.534      88.9610 1.640497e+02     169.6010     209.4940     348.160   100
          cbind      42.241      50.5610 8.019269e+01      61.4405     114.9875     250.455   100
          merge 2142101.821 2256677.2310 2.574166e+06 2416274.7380 2732207.2465 5956733.422   100
```

`data.table` is not my cup of tea but I suppose it could be helpful have a solution with it.

Comment: I added an answer with a data.table update join... feel free to add in the benchmarks here, and I will delete the answer..

Comment: @Wimpel, thanks, but I think that it's to you the idea of data.table and, due it's in the tags, I'd like to leave to OP the choice of your answer (and the possibility to you to get the correct answer), till now you get my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

building on @s_t answer, here is a benchmark of an update join using `data.table`

```
DT1 = data.frame(A = rep('A', 300000), B = rep('B', 300000))
DT2 = data.frame(C = rep('C', 300000), D = rep('D', 300000))

library(data.table)
setDT(DT1)
setDT(DT2)


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cbind = {
    dt1    <-copy(DT1)
    dt2    <-copy(DT2)
    result <- cbind(DT1, DT2)
  },
  update_join = {
    dt1    <-copy(DT1)
    dt2    <-copy(DT2)
    dt1[, id := .I][ dt2[, id := .I], c("C", "D") := .(i.C, i.D), on = .(id)][, id := NULL]
  } )

# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
# cbind        1.8889  2.68405  9.454567  2.99505  3.62625 226.4432   100
# update_join 23.9186 24.67530 36.957518 25.62405 36.42760 249.3631   100
```

`cbind()` still wins by a landslide...

Comment: why not just `DT1[, names(DT2) := DT2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try it by merging, just add rownames as a column, and do the merge:

```
DT1 = data.frame(A = rep('A', 3), B = rep('B', 3))
DT1$rowname = rownames(DT1)
DT2 = data.frame(C = rep('C', 3), D = rep('D', 3))
DT2$rowname = rownames(DT2)
DT3 = merge(DT1, DT2, by = 'rowname')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to assign `DT2` as columns of `DT1`:

```
DT1[, colnames(DT2) := DT2]
```

It is considerably faster than `cbind`. Benchmarking:

```
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(A = sample(LETTERS, 1e6, 1), B = sample(1e6))
DT2 <- data.table(C = sample(LETTERS, 1e6, 1), D = sample(1e6))
DT <- copy(DT1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(cbind = cbind(DT1, DT2),
                               ":=" = DT1[, colnames(DT2) := DT2],
                               setup = {DT1 <- copy(DT)})
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  cbind 5.8867 6.56670 15.157835 11.15040 13.27365 80.9990   100
#>     := 4.6967 5.06075  8.011416  5.30005  5.92710 46.9052   100
```